# How can I check to see if a pair of words are only 1 letter different?

Tags: ruby, string, methods

In writing a method to compare 2 words, how can I check to see if the words are only 1 letter different? I'm assuming words are same length and order of letters doesnt matter (see "cobra","bravo").

```
def one_letter_apart?(word1, word2)
```

I expect the results below:

```
one_letter_apart?("abra","abro") == true
one_letter_apart?("cobra","bravo") == true
one_letter_apart?("bravo","tabby") == false
one_letter_apart?("abc","cab") == false
```

I have tried a few ways of manipulating them (splitting,sorting,then setting equal and adding to new array, then counting), but none so far have worked. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not quite sure what do you mean in your second question. Can you please give example?

Comment: What about like "abc" and "cab", the "c" moves from the end to the beginning. Is that one letter different or not? Requirements are generally unclear to me.

Comment: hi josh, for "abc" and "cab", they wouldn't be one letter different for the question I am thinking about. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Your question has been heavily edited for clarity and syntax. In addition, please only ask *one question per question.* Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one makes use of the fact that `String#sub` substitutes only the first thing it finds.

```
def one_different_char?(str, other)
  other_str = other.dup
  str.chars{|char| other_str.sub!(char, '')} #sub! just replaces just one occurence of char
  other_str.size == 1
end


test_set = [["abra","abro"],["cobra","bravo"],["bravo","tabby"],["abc","cab"]]
test_set.each{|first, second| puts one_different_char?(first, second) }

#true
#true
#false
#false
```

Comment: Nice!  This is essentially the same algorithm as mine, but shorter and cleaner because that's a simpler way to remove the first occurrence.

Comment: It breaks if `other` happens to be the same as `str` with on letter appended, e.g. `one_different_char?('abc', 'abcd')`. You'll have to check for the `length`s being equal to get around this.  (This is assuming I understand the requirements correctly.)

Comment: @DarshanComputing Read the question carefully.

Comment: @sawa I read it carefully, I'm just not clear on whether "I'm assuming words are same length and order of letters doesn't matter" means "the method can assume its inputs are the same length" or "the method must ensure that its inputs are the same length".  Maybe it's just me seeing ambiguity when it isn't there, something we're all prone to with natural language.

Answer (score 5):

### Check Levenshtein Distance

You want the [Levenstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). For example, using the [text gem](https://github.com/threedaymonk/text):

```
require 'text'

def one_letter_apart? string1, string2
  Text::Levenshtein.distance(string1, string2).eql? 1
end

one_letter_apart? "abra", "abro"
# => true 
one_letter_apart? "cobra", "bravo"
# => false
```

Comment: Is there a different way of doing this so that "cobra" and "bravo" would return true as the "c" and the "v" are the only letter different? Thanks

Comment: The question has cobra and bravo being one letter apart. If I understand the question right you could fix this by sorting the strings before computing edit distance.

Comment: @Frederick Cheung, the splitted/sorted version would reuslt in ["a","b","o","r","v"] and ["a","b","c","o","r"].

Answer (score 1):

```
def one_letter_apart?(s1, s2)
  return false if s1.length != s2.length

  a2 = s2.chars.to_a
  s1.chars.each do |c|
    if i = a2.index(c)
      a2.delete_at(i)
    end
  end

  a2.length == 1
end

one_letter_apart?("abra","abro") == true
# => true
one_letter_apart?("cobra","bravo") == true
# => true
one_letter_apart?("bravo","tabby") == false
# => true
one_letter_apart?("abc","cab") == false
# => true
```

**Update:** To answer your question of how it works: This is the exact same general algorithm as steenslag's, but I didn't think of using `String#sub!` to do the removal, so I converted to arrays and used a combination of `index` and `delete_at` to remove the first occurrence of the given character.  The naïve approach is `a2.delete_at(a2.index(c))`, but if the character `c` doesn't exist in `a2`, then `index` returns `nil`, which is an invalid input for `delete_at`.  The workaround is to only call `delete_at` if `index` returns something non-`nil`, which is what I've done.  `i` is declared and set to `a2.index(c)`, and the value of that assignment is evaluated by `if`.  It's the same as:

```
i = a2.index(c)
if i
  # ...
```

I much prefer steenslag's approach and would have done the exact same thing if I'd thought of `String#sub!`.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding where/how your variable i is declared? Would greatly appreciate if you could explain this.

Comment: @JamieS My explanation is too long for a comment; I've added it as an update to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This function returns true if two strings have equal lengths and only one different letter while all the other letters are in the same positions:

```
def one_letter_apart? string1, string2
  return false if string1.size != string2.size
  found = false
  (0...string1.size).each do |i|
    next if string1[i] == string1[i]
    return false if found  # if found is already true, and we found another difference, then result is false.
    found = true  # We found the first difference.
  end
  found  # True if only one difference was found.
end
```

This function handles letters in wrong positions (like "cobra" and "bravo") as well:

```
def one_letter_apart? string1, string2
  letters1 = string1.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, h| h[c] += 1 }
  letters2 = string2.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c, h| h[c] -= 1 }
  diff = letters1.merge(letters2) { |key, count1, count2| count1 + count2 }
  return diff.values.select { |v| v != 0 } .sort == [-1, 1]
end
```

Comment: This is clean and great for all situations except situations where the letters are scrambled around. It wouldn't return true for                 one_letter_apart?("cobra","bravo")

Comment: @JamieS added a solution for that case as well.